# Separate php error log for all apps

Tags: apache2, php, log

I have a Linux Apache server and my error log for PHP is going to `/etc/my_custom_php_error_log.log` as I mentioned in `php.ini` file.
But I want to create this logs in separate for all my applications.
For example I have deployed two applications in this server names Alpha and Bravo and I want to create error logs for Alpha in `/var/www/html/Aplha/php_alpha.log` and
for Bravo in `/var/www/html/Bravo/php_bravo.log`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done in their various `VirtualHost` files as thus:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName ensignremake.app
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ensignremake/public/
        DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/ensignremake>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /path/where/you/want/the/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        php_value error_log "/path/where/you/want/the/error.log"

</VirtualHost>
```

1. Please note from the most upvoted answer on the link below that other `php flags` can be set for individual apps but not needed if already set globally in `php`.
2. And the right `permissions` must also be set for your custom locations or `apache` will write to it's own `log files`

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176/error-log-per-virtual-host

Comment: Similar, good explanation can be found also here: https://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/